# Jquery toggle or hide/show elements that have their links on other parents by order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I guys, let me start that if you have seen my problem on other post or reference redirect me to that. I couldn't find anything with my specific problem.

My problem is that i want to link actions from one child to a child on other parent like so:

```
<div class="parent1">
 <i class="link1"></i>
 <i class="link2"></i>
 <i class="link3"></i>
</div>

<div class="parent2">
 <div class="logo-case"></div>
 <div class="logo-case"></div>
 <div class="logo-case"></div>
</div>
```

I know the js is not right (duh) but i want to illustrate an ideia of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
$('.parent1 i').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(){
     $('**all** .logo-case').css("height", "0");
     $(' **this** .logo-case').css("height", "100%");
    )};
});
```

Now I want that the first "i.link1" gives height to the first "logo-case" no matter of the classes added to "logo-case" which means "link1" always affects the first "logo-case" and so on.

Thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6jaj5L0y/1/

I think it achieves what you are trying to do.

```
$('.parent1 i').each(function(idx, el) {
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(".parent2 .logo-case").css({height: '0px'})
                                .eq(idx).css({height: '100px'});
  });
});
```